# How to avoid truncation of body title name while hovering chrome tabs

Tags: html, css, web-deployment-project, page-title, format-truncation

a rookie developer here.
I am facing this problem, as when I hover over other website tab in Chrome the title is getting displayed without truncation even though they are longer than mine, but when I hover over my tab in Chrome, the title getting truncate. Why so?

Example:
[My Tab] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04vJj.jpg)

[Other website tab] [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frpg3.jpg)

I tried with some CSS property in  tag but nothing worked.
I want to display entire title w/o truncate
"Ahemar Khan | Graphic Designer and Artist"

Comment: You can't. That's a browser function not an HTML issue.

Comment: but other people are having it displayed perfectly. My title description in shorter than theirs yet mine is not displayed the way they have it displayed. What I noticed is, in their case the title is appearing in two lines (check the image '2'). where as mine title is not appearing in two lines, its just one single line with truncation. That's what bugging me.